# High Poly Mesh UV Mapping

Tags: mesh, uv

I am still in the learning stages of Mesh modeling, but I've just sculpted two well looking Mesh Sci-fi helmets and I wish to have them textured by a Friend. I tried to UV map both of them but they both froze after clicking 'Unwrap'. Im positive it must be too high polly, and if so how could I fix this problem? Or how could I get a viable texture map a different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since, it is not possible to unwrap a highpoly sculpted mesh (i am thinking about 500k polys) in blender. You are left with few choices.

duplicate your highpoly mesh, add a deciamte modifier, decimate and apply the modifier. Turn your Triangles to Quad and then unwrap it. You can always get Details by baking normals. (Worst idea in my opinon, but fastest).

or

Retopologize your model (best option) , unwrap retopo and bake normals, ao, cavity maps.
(retopo is good too , when you want Hard surface and edges too).

By the way, There is no point in giving highpoly mesh to your friend for texturing, as it wont be usable in game, but render only.

Comment: How would I go about Retopologizing it? And would doing so allow him to be able to Texture it then?

Comment: @user2016 For retopo you would create a new low-poly mesh on top of the sculpted one using the snapping tool. To explain how this works you would need a tutorial like: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/08/30/retopology-and-normal/

Comment: It don't anwser how to unwrap high poly photogrammetry without realitycapture

Answer (score 0):

Handwork way:

1. Imagine your model dissected on several most plain parts, like front of face, back of body, left side of finger (you need to dissect your model like animal and put its skin on texture)
2. Open your mesh in edit mode and change selection mode to faces
3. Look at plain spot and select its faces with C or B selection tool
4. Press U and select cube projection
5. Rotate, move and scale your dissected part in Blender's Image editor
6. Repeat with every part

You can check your work in real time with Textured view.